# How can I query MySQL with node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I am going to make a client-server application using Node.js, and I want to use a MySQL database for storing some of the data. I need to know how to query a database with server-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Search the module library](http://search.npmjs.org/) for *mysql* and you will get many modules that will let you do that including [mysql](http://search.npmjs.org/#/mysql), [db-mysql](http://search.npmjs.org/#/db-mysql), and [easy-mysql](http://search.npmjs.org/#/easy-mysql).

Answer (score 4):

npm install node-mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql'),
    client = mysql.createClient({
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
    });

mysql.query('SELECT * FROM my_table', function(err, results, fields) {
    //have fun         
    client.end();
});
```

There are other libraries as well that all have slightly different APIs.